# How to spread VUsers across multiple test agents when running load test

Tags: controller, visual-studio-2015, load-testing, agent

I'm trying to run a load test in visual studio 2015. I have 1 test controller with 3 test agents setup. I have set the weighting of the agents to 33 each as I would like to spread the userload evenly across them. When I run the test I see evidence that it tries log in with the same user on all 3 agents, and as the tests are running I'm observing that there is 1 successfull login and 2 failed / user, which I assume is happening because they all try to log in at once.

How can I make sure that 1 Vuser is assigned to one agent only? (1 agent can have multiple users of course)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `Access method` property of the data source to `Unique`. See [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/slumley/archive/2008/03/14/description-of-access-methods-in-data-sources.aspx) for more details. In brief, for the `Sequential` and `Random` access methods a full copy of all of the data is sent to each agent. For `Unique` the data is split into pieces and each agent gets one piece, thus maintaining the desired "use each data value only once".