# Visual Studio Load Test - Using Data Source with Multiple Agents

Tags: visual-studio, performance-testing, load-testing

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Load Test and running a Web Performance test that has a data source connected. The data source contains user login information for 250 users.

Running this in sequential order on a single agent works fine.  However, I'm attempting to add in 10 test agents to share out the load.  By design the Load Test copies the data source to each agent and it runs the test.  What ends up happening is that all 10 agents start the test using the row 1 user from the data source.  I'm hoping there's away to set up the Load Test to run sequentially across all agents (ex: Agent 1 uses row 1, Agent 2 uses row 2, Agent 3 uses row 3, etc...)

I suspect there's not an option to set this up, but wondered if anyone ran into this and had workarounds to offer.  I did find this info via http://vsptqrg.codeplex.com

> Multiple machines running as a rig
>
> Sequential – This works that same as if you are on one machine. Each agent receives a full copy of the data and each starts with row 1 in the data source. Then each agent will run through each row in the data source and continue looping until the load test completes.
>
> Random – This also works the same as if you run the test on one machine. Each agent will receive a full copy of the data source and randomly select rows.
>
> Unique – This one works a little differently. Each row in the data source will be used once. So if you have 3 agents, the data will be spread across the 3 agents and no row will be used more than once. As with one machine, once every row is used, the web test will stop executing.

Answer (score 0):

The nearest you can get to what you want is to use the `unique` setting. However each data source row will only be used once, then the test will stop. With a data source containing 250 line only 250 test executions will take place. I do not know the exact distribution of data source rows to agents when `unique` is specified.

If more than one execution per data source row is wanted then another approach is to have one data source column per agent. Use the agent_id to select the column. Use the `sequential` data source access. A variation is to just have one set of data in the data source but append the agent_id to some of the values in the data sources. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38362646/546871) has some variations on these ideas and some code.

---

Another possibility is to use the `MoveDataTableCursor` method to set a specific row for each test execution. This could be called in a `PreWebTest` method of a `WebTestPlugin`. The code would use the context parameters `$AgentId` and `$WebTestIteration`. The call would be based the following:

```
MoveDataTableCursor(..., ..., $AgentId * NumberOfAgents + $WebTestIteration);
```

Notes:

- The values of `$AgentId` and `$WebTestIteration` from the context are strings, they would need to be converted to numbers to do the multiply and add.
- Would also need to check whether the two values are zero-based or one-based.
- The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee308186.aspx) for `MoveDataTableCursor` is not very informative

Comment: Thanks AdrianHHH, I think the second option would probably work for me.  I'll experiment and report back.

Comment: Well, come to find out that each agent uses it's own $WebTestIteration :(  Using the "Random" order may be the best option for me.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Split the Data set/CSV and distribute to each Agent, i.e in your case "25 data set"/agent and execute the test.

Each Agent can use their own Data set/CSV.

CSV Split: http://monchito.com/blog/autosplit-csv

Comment: Can you please explain how, within a Visual Studio load test, you would give each agent the same ".webtest" file but different CSVs.

Comment: I'm assuming in this example I would end up with 10 webtest with each one assigned their own CSV file.  Can the VS load test be configured to run a test on only one agent?

Comment: @bigspank Yes. Have a scenario for each agent set the "Agents to use" property of the scenario as required.

Comment: CSV Split

Step#1: split -l 200 example.csv

Step#2: for i in *; do mv "$i" "$i.csv"; done