# How can i use one data source for multiple test cases in Load test

Tags: visual-studio, automated-tests, performance-testing, load-testing, software-quality

I have created Performance test cases on Visual studio 2017, The issue i am facing is i have to make all of the test case get through login Data source, 
As in Load test they will run parallel, The question is how can i use one data source to run for all the test cases 
Instead of adding data source for all the test cases

Thank You in advance

Answer (score 0):

Data sources are added to Web Performance Tests. They are not added to load tests. If all the web tests need a login then each test needs to have a suitable data source added. If the login actions can be written in a called web test (see the `Insert call to web test` command in the web test editor) then that login (i.e. called) web test could have a datasource for the username and password etc.

One data source can be used by several web tests within the same load test. Each web test will have its own data access method (i.e. `Unique` or `Sequential` or `Random` etc). That means that the same login data may be used by two or more test executions at the same time. If one data source file is needed but each test must use different logins then see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41989496/546871) for some ideas.